Why do vector objects I've uploaded to a Creative Cloud library paste as raster graphics when I pull them out of the library to use?
For example, I have a vector logo I use often. I dragged it into my CC library, but when I pull it from my library into any doc, it shows up as a raster.
Is it possible for it to come out as vector? Is the dragging and dropping into the library a problem?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What application are you dragging it into?  If it's InDesign, you might only be seeing a low resolution preview.  I can't reproduce this problem with Illustrator. Vectors pulled from the Library import as linked vector objects in Illustrator.  Also check you don't have Pixel Preview switched on in Illustrator (just in case). In InDesign you can increase the preview quality in Preferences > Display Performance.

If you are dragging it into Photoshop, yes it will look rasterized (because Photoshop is a raster editor), however it should still be a vector object.  You should still be able to enlarge it without pixelization.
